# How did I win without killing my opponent?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

I'm a little confused. I was playing a game with 3 bots, two had been eliminated, and it was down to just me and one last robot. We were both using the same deck ([Ajani](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920044649/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/digital/duelsoftheplaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/d13/decklists#ajani)), and gaining life like mad. I got him down to about 10 when he planeswalked, there was a chaotic reshuffling of everything, and he bounced back to around 80, and one of his creatures was at 65/65.

He doesn't attack (though he should have) because I had a 47/47 creature, and a bunch of moderate units (3 or 4 around 6/6, and 3 or 4 around 2/2), and ends his turn. At that point, because of the plainswalk and the chaos, it starts counting like mad. I was at roughly 200 health, and my 47/47 guy was just starting to get all of his increments from all of my health and the other creatures. However, at this point, during my turn, while it was adding to my life during the start phase, and powering up all my creatures, it tells me I won. It doesn't even get through the end of the start phase before it does it. I got 2 achievements for it, but nothing indicating why I might have won. My stats page now lists my highest life total at 224 (which is what it was when it stopped), and my highest power creature at 47.

Now I know at least two of the win conditions, but neither make sense here. The first being my opponent had 0 life, but I wasn't doing any damage, so that can't be the case. The second is if they run out of cards, but they weren't drawing any cards and still had probably 15 or so left.

So, the tl;dr version. **What are the different win conditions in the game?** Did I just hit a glitch, or is there some way I could have won during my start phase that I just don't know about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You hadn't by chance played a [Felidar Sovereign](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Felidar%20Sovereign) on the last turn, did you?

It's also possible your opponent gained life on your turn *(there are many cards in that deck that could have caused this)*, and he stupidly used something like [Lost Dreams](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Well%20of%20Lost%20Dreams) to draw his last cards.  The poor UI in Magic 2013 would have thrown you immediately into the 'Game won' screen without giving you a chance to see that.

To answer your question in bold:  hitting 0 life or running out of cards are the only two losing conditions, unless a card in play adds *(or removes)* more.

Comment: Because of the last planeswalk and the chaos it introduced, he may have come into play during my opponents turn. But, when does that activate in the digital version? Because the start of my turn had done a few cycles of giving me life *before* I got the game over screen. Does it do it after life is given? Also, there were only 2 artifacts in play, and neither were Lost Dreams, so I don't think it's that one.

Comment: @Ktash When your upkeep starts, all of the abilities that trigger at upkeep are put on the stack. Technically, they're put there in an order you choose, but the game probably picks an order for you. Then the game would have just worked down the stack until it hit the win condition ability, and then you would have won. It might have put it after all of the life gain abilities to make sure that you had enough life.